# ASP.NET Core: Generate URL to the base of a controller (NOT TO AN ACTION)

Tags: asp.net-core, url

I need to use `UrlHelper` to generate the URL to the base of a controller. If you must know, the action is `Statements`, but that is generated by JavaScript provided by a third party that is out of my control. Read: If the name of ANY action, including `Statements` or `Index`, is in the generated URL, then my application will fail. Thank you!!!

Stuart Simon

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have the name of the controller as a string?  Or are you calling this in the controller and you need the URL to point to the current controller?  Also, what version of .Net Core are you targeting?

Comment: I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and I'm trying to access it from _another_ controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of `RouteAttribute` and `Url.RouteUrl`.

Controller:

```
[Route("test", Name = "test-route")]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This associates the name `test-route` with `/test`. Calling `Url.RouteUrl("test-route")` will return `/test`.